# iMessage Conversation Freeze

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, messages, performance

I was messaging a friend then suddenly it gave me an error saying the message was not sent and I had to re-try sending the message. Since then, my iMessage freezes if I go into that same message. I cannot delete that conversation because if I go back (does not freeze if my screen is not in a conversation) and press edit then delete, it reappears every 5 seconds. This one conversation seems to be the one with the glitch.

iMessage opens at that specific broken conversation by default. So I have to tap back within 1.5 seconds before it freeze to go to my list of conversations.

I have an iPod Touch 4G and my software is updated to iOS 6.1.

I have tried:

- Force close
- Delete all conversations
- Restart iPod
- Turn off and back on
- Clear messages in that conversation within 1.5s (I cleared it but still freezes)
- Send new messages
- Power off my iPod for 24 hrs.

**Is there a way to delete that conversation on my macbook?**

Comment: I am still experiencing this problem.

Comment: Anybody? Please help me with this problem...